# is there a maximum number of members for EE?

Tags: members

is there a maximum number of members for EE?
I'm debating using EE to create a membership website for a yearly program.  Each year 500 member accounts would be created.

Thanks

Peter T

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no maximum number of members in EE.

Answer (score 1):

500 per year will be no problem at all. There are EE sites running tens of thousands of members, and I would be surprised if it cannot handle hundreds of thousands (athough at that point you may need to look at measuring and optimizing your SQL indexes, but that would apply regardless of the CMS or framework you chose).